# VoIP with Godaddy Server

Tags: voip

I would like to know how I can have VoIP on a godaddy Linux server.
I want to be able to pc-pc talk to another computer from mine.
Yet I dont want to pay for anything.
I can try and learn how to script if you put me in the right direction.
But I would like to know how i can do this. Do I use a VoIP engine or just an application that i can install on my server ?

Comment: Not clear, and doesn't sound programming-related.

Comment: Don't know where you're going to find a free godaddy app server

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use something like Skype, which provides free PC to PC voice chat?

Comment: @ziplin because i want to use this on my website. So a user can call another user

Comment: in browser Flash SIP client + Asterisk backend would be a neat feature on a website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try and install Asterisk on this server.

Comment: it's been a while, but Asterisk is awesome.